# Java Arraylist gets re-initialized after every iteration of the for loop

Tags: java, android, parsing, arraylist

I really need help with this problem. Here's a part of the code. I am supposed to parse all files before writing the output in a textfile. Problem is, its writing either just the parsed 1st xml or 2nd xml file.

The writing method:

```
new LoadCoordinatesTask().execute();
Button btncoor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.File);
btncoor.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (isSDCardWritable()) {
                              StringBuilder locationStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                              locationStrBuilder.append(coordinates + "\n");
                              String locationStr = locationStrBuilder.toString();
                        try {
                            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/FileReader");
                            directory.mkdirs();
                            File myFile = new File(directory, fileCoord);

                       myFile.createNewFile();
                       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
                       OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                       myOutWriter.append(locationStr);
                       myOutWriter.close();
                       fOut.close();
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Successfully downloaded coordinates.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      } 
                      catch (Exception e) {
                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      } }
                      else 
                        {
                            // SD Card Not Available
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SD Card Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } //else

                    }// onClick 
                }); 
                }
```

FilenameFilter method:

```
public FilenameFilter xmlFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
       @override
       public boolean accept (File dir,String name) {
              return name.endsWith(".xml") || name.endsWith (".XML")
}
};
     private class LoadCoordinatesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Coordinates>> {
         for (String filename : dir.list(xmlFilter)) {
              String path = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename;
              Log.i (TAG, path);
              coordinates.addAll(parser.parse(path));
              Log.i (TAG, "message");
         }
     return coordinates;
   }
```

Log shows this:

```
Test    /storage/sdcard/Garmin/01.xml
Test    /storage/sdcard/Garmin/02.xml
Test    message
Test    message
```

But the printing only shows output from **/storage/sdcard/Garmin/01.xml** *twice*

Comment: `files.length` returns??

Comment: What is `f`? You aren't using the `i` in your for loop, so its just executing the same code twice

Comment: You probably need `files[i]` instead of `f`

Comment: Sir @Rod_Algonquin, **files.length** returns how many files are there in the storage. its from a FilenameFilter method

Comment: Sir @AlexBaker, **f** is from a FilenameFilter method, it is the filepath of the filename that i am parsing.

Comment: editing the code to add the FilenameFilter method

Comment: You are reassigning `f` in `foreach`, so `f` will always equal the last entry in `files`, which you are then parsing twice

Comment: Sir @AlexBaker, how can I fix that then? I put a **Log.d** and it shows the 2 files and their filepath. How can fix that so that it will not re-assign or re-initialize the value of f?

Comment: Where are you using `args` passed to method `doInBackground`?

Comment: Also I believe while editing you have removed the part that mentioned about the problem you are facing with this code. Please correct the code so that we can get better idea of the problem.

Comment: Where is the printing code?

Comment: Sir @akhil_mittal, that's the code, I just deleted the part that I have mistakenly added (about the doInBackground, its from another method, sorry). My real problem was that, I am just printing output from either the 1st or 2nd xml file, which is not what I needed.

Comment: It seems either there is some problem with code `parser.parse(path)` or may be you are re-initializing the `coordinates`somewhere. I cannot think of any other problem. From logs it seems that the code is able to pick both files.

Comment: posted the writing method Sir @AlexBaker

Comment: Sir @akhil_mittal, yes the log does show all the files in the storage, but i am wondering why the output shows that only one file is being parsed. Yes, maybe I am re-initializing the **path**,  that is why it only shows  only 1 file being parsed. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: can you try printing `coordinates` in the for loop after invoking `addAll`?

Comment: the output is still the first xml.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code you are reassigning `coordinates` a new list object to point to and that's why it will be reinitialized.

```
public List<Coordinates> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= files.length; i++) {
    coordinates = parser.parse (f);
    }
    return coordinates;
```

You should try:

```
public List<Coordinates> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();

for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++) {
coordinates.addAll(parser.parse (f));
}
return coordinates;
```

Also what is type of variable `f` as I cannot locate it in the code. I believe it should have been of type File but cannot guess as you have not specified. Once you do then I will edit my answer.

Comment: I tried the **should-try** code, and its printing the last read(parsed) file twice. Just like the 2nd code that I have tried., Already edited the code to add the FilenameFilter method

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
public FilenameFilter xmlFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
       @override
       public boolean accept (File dir,String name) {
              return name.endsWith(".xml") || name.endsWith (".XML")
}
};

String files[] = dir.list(xmlFilter);
File f;
public List<Coordinates> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinates>();
for (String file_name:files) {
   f=dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filename;
   coordinates.addAll(parser.parse (f));
}
return coordinates;
```

Nope?

Comment: Thank you Sir, with that code, it only prints the 2nd xml file, twice. Y_Y